# algorithm with O(logn) and θ(logn) time-complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

If we have 2 algorthims. One of them is `O(f(x))` time-complexity and the other on is `θ(f(x))` time-complexity. Which one we prefer  to solve our problem? and why?

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information given to decide which algorithm is preferable. It's possible that the first algorithm is preferable, it's possible that both are equally preferable, and it's even possible the second is preferable if they are asymptotically equal but the second has a lower constant factor.

1. Consider the fact that binary search is O(n) because big-O only gives an upper bound, whereas linear search is Θ(n). Binary search is preferable, because it is asymptotically more efficient.
2. Consider linear search, which is O(n), and... linear search, which is Θ(n). Both are equally preferable because they are literally the same.
3. Consider bubble sort, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>), and insertion sort, which is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). Insertion sort does on average ~ n<sup>2</sup>/4 comparisons, whereas bubble sort does on average ~ n<sup>2</sup>/2 comparisons, which is twice as many; so insertion sort is preferable.

So as you can see, it's not possible to say without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to compare the algorithms:

First algorithm has `O(nlogn)` time complexity which means that execution time `t1` is

```
 t1 <= k1 * n * log(n) + o(n * log(n))
```

Second algorithm is `θ(nlogn)`, that's why

```
 t2 = k2 * n * log(n) + o(n * log(n))
```

Assuming that `n` is *large enough* so we can neglect `o(n * log(n))` term, we still have *two* possibilities here.

1. `t1 < n * log(n)`
2. `t1 = k1 * n * log(n)` (at least for some *worst* case)

In the first case we should prefer algorithm `2` for large `n`, since algorithm `1` has a shorter execution time when `n` is large enough.

In the second case we have to compare *unknown* `k1` and `k2`, we have not enough information to choose from 1st and 2nd algorithms.

Comment: @ddffc: we have the similar two cases: `O(n^2)` means `t <= k * n ^ 2 + o(n ^ 2)`; if `t < k * n^2` we prefer the 1st algorithm, if `t = k * n^2` we should compare unknown coefficients